# does the capturing and bubbling phases reaches the event.target node?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, dom-events, terminology

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#bubbling_and_capturing_explained) modern browsers run two different phases when an event is fired:

- The capture phase (evt.target included)
- The bubbling phase (evt.target included)

[According to WHATWG](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-event-stoppropagation%E2%91%A0) event.stopPropagation() prevents event from reaching any objects other than the current object.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation() prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

So i would like to know whether or not is correct to say that the capturing and bubbling phases reaches the event.target node.

Comment: Write a test that tests your hypothesis. Run that test in as many browsers as you want. Record the results. Publish the results. ... Profit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the capturing and bubbling phases **does not** reaches the event.target node.

modern browsers run three different phases, the capturing phase, the target phase, and the bubbling phase.

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-eventphase

https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/6657